# how to parse mysql json column in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I use `CaptureChangeMySQL` + `ConvertJSONToSQL` + `PutSQL` to sync data from mysql(5.7), in my table there is a json type column, I want to convert json to sql literal, use `new String((bytep[]) json, StandardCharset.UTF_8)` to parse it but get wrong result:[image]

byte[] is:

[image]

The actual value in table is:
`[{id: 13182, name: "2730"}]`

So how can I parse mysql json value correctly?

Comment: `new String((bytep[]) json, StandardCharset.UTF_8)` - what is that? are you using executescript? please provide details.

Comment: @daggett, not use executescript, I remote debug nifi, and in `MySQLCDCUtils.getWritableObject()` to evaluate `new String((bytep[]) json, StandardCharset.UTF_8)`, the evaluation result is the first image I posted.

Comment: could you provide info about your question: table definition, properties of the processors,...

Comment: @daggett I have solved, it is `binlog-connect` problem, use `JsonBinary.parseAsString()` to parse `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

use `JsonBinary.parseAsString(byte[])` to parse.